# Program to check whether string is pallindrome or not. I typed the below code in that when i reverse my string both str1 and str2 gets reversed

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

Program to check whether string is pallindrome or not. I typed the below code in that when i reverse my string both str1 and str2 gets reversed.

package com.shrey;

import java.util.*;

public class basics {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    StringBuilder str1 = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder str2 = new StringBuilder();
    System.out.println("Enter String: ");
    String str = sc.nextLine();
    str1.append(str);
    str2=str1;
    str2=str2.reverse();
    if(str1==str2)
        System.out.println("Strings are PALLINDROME!");
    else
        System.out.println("Strings are not pallindrome");
    sc.close();
}
```

}

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: What is your output? and what is your question?

Comment: `StringBuilder.reverse()` returns itself, so `str2=str1; str2=str2.reverse();` is equivalent to `str1.reverse(); str2=str1;`, so the equality check will always evaluate to true. And if they weren't the same instance, it would always be false because `==` does reference comparison, and so does `StringBuilder.equals()` for that matter.

Comment: `str2=str1;` sets str2 to the same object as str1. `str2.append(str1);`

Comment: Give ``` str2=new String(str1);``` . This way , the value of str1 gets copied to str2 and you won't get the issue . ```str2=str1``` means that both str1 and str2 points to single String object and when a change is made for str1 or str2 , it gets reflected in both